# Installing R Studio without Admin Rights on Windows 10

Tags: r, rstudio

While I was able to install R under my username, I am not able to the same for R studio. Is admin rights essential for R studio installation ? Will I face problems with package installations in future ?

Comment: Do you simply want to run R code? For that you can use the default environment, installable without admin rights: https://cran.r-project.org/

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: In my experience, R Studio has required the privilege.  You can circumvent it from [here](http://dainiuxt.github.io/2016/02/02/Install-update-portable-r-rstudio-windows.html).

Solution 2: In the limited environments I am using [Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/). It is not an RStudio enviroment. It based on Jupyter Notebook. However, performing any analysis is quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

RStudio provide a zip file of the required binaries for Windows 10. Download and then extract it, then run \bin\rstudio.exe.

It's possible that when I once had admin privileges and installed RStudio that I still have some essential dependencies to allow it run. I have seen a report that some have trouble with the zip distribution.